# Angular4 not processing selectors for components/directives for dom elements inserted dynamically

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-directives

Why angular4 is not applying components/directives/bindings on the dynamically created dom elements.

I have a directive which is having a selector as 'span' so it applies to all the spans in the application.  But if a span is inserted dynamically in the dom, the directive is not applied.  How to make it working?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <span>Testing</span>
    <div id="dynamic">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    const elem = document.getElementById('dynamic');
    elem.innerHTML = '<span>Span inserted on the fly!!!</span>';

  }
}


@Directive({
  selector: 'span'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PXiXgqYic4qsUYsDfWKk?p=preview

Comment: You can inject components into specific locations

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: any of these you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Comment: with the click of a button, for example, you could instantiate a component and inject it into a location using its ComponentFactoryResolver. If you're looking for a way to dynamically compile a string and process its directives, that's a lot harder, especially with AOT.

Comment: i think, thats like on angular1, to need to 'compile' your can, that angular know he need to do something. This way you working outside of angular controlled environment.